# Uncaught ReferenceError: handleClick is not defined - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'll go straight to the point. This is the component I have in a ReactJS application:

```
class BooksList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

  }

  handleClick() {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("The link was clicked");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a className="btn btn-success" onClick={handleClick}>
            Add to cart
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Why do I get the following error when the component is loaded?

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: handleClick is not defined
```

**EDIT:**

After you answers I changed my code to this:

```
  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Item added to the cart");
  }


  renderBooks(){
      return this.props.myBooks.data.map(function(book){
          return (
                  <div className="row">
                    <table className="table-responsive">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <p className="bookTitle">{book.title}</p>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>                                  
                             <button value={book._id} onClick={this.handleClick}>Add to cart</button>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
          );
      });
    }
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h3>Buy our books</h3>
              {this.renderBooks()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

As you can see I have `.map` which iterate through a list of books.
For each of the books I have a button that, if clicked, will add the specific book to the user's cart.

If I follow @Tharaka Wijebandara answer I can make a button work outside `.map` but in this case I still get the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined
    at http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:41331:89
    at Array.map (native)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution for issue you mentioned in edit part.

Reason is, you are loosing the `context` in `map` callback function, you need to `bind` this (class context) with callback function or Use `arrow function`, it will solve your issue.

By using [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
renderBooks(){
      return this.props.myBooks.data.map((book) => { //here
          return (
                  .....
          );
      });
  }
```

Or use `.bind(this)` with callback function, like this:

```
renderBooks(){
      return this.props.myBooks.data.map(function (book) {
          return (
                  .....
          );
      }.bind(this));    //here
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `this.handleClick`

```
<a className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.handleClick}>
  Add to cart
</a>
```

and you have forgot to add `e` as an argument in your `handleClick` method.

```
handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("The link was clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Tharaka Wijebandara answer, you can alternatively declare function as `const`, as follows:

```
render() {
     const handleClick = this.handleClick;
     return (
         <div>
            <a className="btn btn-success" onClick={handleClick}>
                  Add to cart
            </a>
         </div>
     );
}
```

where `handleClick` is defined as:

```
handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("The link was clicked");
}
```